# C# .NET Application slows down throughout day until recycling application pool at night

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, iis

We have a .NET C# web application that we are seeing a significant slowdown throughout the day on. By the end of the day, we have to restart the application pool and it works fast after that. But the next day, by the end, once again we have to restart the application pool.

The site is very slow towards the end of the day in the afternoon and users are having a hard time using it with it this slow. I've read that there could be memory leaks causing this. Could MySQL queries also be causing this?

Are there any tools to help pinpoint memory leaks or SQL queries that haven't been closed properly. I ask because this has been an application that has been built in modules over a few years and there's no easy way of manually going through everything.

Comment: You can try running the Sql Profiler, but no idea if that covers unclosed connections. And you can set the recycle settings to "every x minutes" in IIS in your application pool.

Comment: I'm running mysql, not mssql. Weird, I know, but that's how this thing was started years ago to tie into other software non-.net

Comment: If the app pool recycles, don't all our users drop their connection? They're all logging into the system and it's my understanding that if you recycle an application pool it kicks people's sessions.

Comment: Forgot mysql, and I think it does drop connections, but not sure myself. You might want to experiment with that.

Comment: Do not recycle every x minutes. You have a problem in your app. Either memory problem, open connections or open files. Check memory consumption, open ports and so on

Comment: I agree - I think it's a memory leak or something of that nature because when I restart the application pool it immediately speeds back up. We store things in session (small things) but could that accumulate with enough users? My app pools are only around 175 megabytes but the site gets sluggish in the evenings and as soon as the app pools reset at night (once a day) it speeds right back up until the next evening. How can I check what's in the worker process memory for the application pool?